# Cannot seem to bind function to view in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to bind `checkScroll()` to the view `PhotoListView` so that I can call `this.checkScroll()` from within `$(Window).scroll()` without first having `var self = this` then calling `self.checkScroll()`.

**Problem:** However the binding does not seem to work, and I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'checkScroll'` Am I binding it wrongly?

**VIEW**

```
PhotoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#photo_list',

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'checkScroll');
        this.bind('checkScroll', this)

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            this.checkScroll();
        });
    },

    checkScroll: function() {
        console.log('checkScroll');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'checkScroll');
    $(window).scroll(this.checkScroll)
},
```

`_.bindAll` will take `this.checkScroll` and fix its context to `this`, so you can just pass it directly as a handler. But you threw it away by using anonymous function.

Note that there are 2 different concepts of "binding" going on:

- Binding a function to an object, so that no matter how the function is invoked, it will have fixed `this` value
- Attaching a handler to an event for an element

`_.bindAll` does the former.

---

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yepUg/)

Comment: I tried without using the annoymous function, and the scroll handler is only fired once. With the annoymous function, its continuously being fired! Thats strange, I'm looking to have it fire continuously.

Comment: @Nyxynyx that's very strange, can you make a jsfiddle

Comment: @Nyxynyx I made a js fiddle and it's working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yepUg/

Comment: Works fine in Chrome/Mac, I tried it just now on Chrome/Win and had a difference, will return later to check it again.

Comment: @Nyxynyx I am on chrome/win and the jsfiddle works for me normally. If you were talking about your own code, please review any possible differences with it and the jsfiddle because the code should work just fine in normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var view = this; //add this
$(window).scroll(function() {
    view.checkScroll(); //change "this" to "view"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem with your code was loss of context of `this`.
by removing the inline function and providing a straight refrence to the function you avoided the loss of context on the closure.

But, if you still want to use an inline function, or perform a series of functions you can still use the same code, wrapping the function with a proxy that exposes the appropriate context.

You would have to proxy the  the function and provide it with the appropriate scope:

using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
$(window).scroll(_.bind(function() {
    this.checkScroll();
    this.anotherFunction();
},this));
```

using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/):

```
$(window).scroll($.proxy(function() {
    this.checkScroll();
    this.anotherFunction();
},this));
```